# Is it possible to reduce a fraction to the lowest form in a single recursive pass, using no auxiliary functions other than is_zero, succ and pred?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, recursion, functional-programming, greatest-common-divisor

Is it possible to reduce a fraction to the lowest form, in a single recursive pass, using no auxiliary function other than `is_zero`, `succ` and `pred`? As an example, if we wanted to implement **gcd** that way, we could write it as follows:

```
// gcd(a, b, c) returns the greatest common divisor of `a+c` and `b+c`
function gcd(a, b, c)
  if is_zero(a):
    if is_zero(b):
      c
    else:
      gcd(c, b, 0)
  else:
    if is_zero(b):
      gcd(a, c, 0)
    else:
      gcd(pred(a), pred(b), succ(c))
```

Notice how this function is a direct recursion that **does not use any auxiliary function other than is_zero, succ and pred**. It does require one extra argument, though, which stores the result. It is also tail-recursive, but that isn't a demand. My question is: is it possible to do the same, but for `reduce_fraction`?

```
// reduce_fraction(a, b, ...) returns a pair 
// with the `a/b` fraction in the lowest form
function reduce_fraction(a, b, ...):
  ...
```

Note that using GCD to implement `reduce_fraction` isn't allowed:

```
function reduce_fraction(a,b):
  return (a / gcd(a,b), b / gcd(a,b))
```

Because `reduce_fraction` would call 2 auxiliary functions (`gcd` and `/`), which is **not** allowed by definition. It must be a direct recursion using only `is_zero`, `succ` and `pred`.

I'm specifically looking for a solution that reduces the space used (number of auxiliary arguments) and time used (total recursive steps).

Comment: Isn't the GCD of numerator and denominator all you need to simplify the fraction though?

Comment: @Useless Yes, but that isn't what the question is asking. I'd edited it to address your comment.

Comment: Yes. First calculate the gcd as before, storing 2 copies of the result in additional accumulator arguments, then implement division of the numerator by calling `pred` on both the numerator and one of the gcd accumulator arguments until the former `is_zero`; whenever the latter `is_zero`, reset it from the other copy of the gcd and `succ` an additional `num_quotient` accumulator argument. Do likewise for the denominator, then return them both.

Comment: Your `gcd` has an extra parameter.  If you can add extra parameters, then those parameters can be used to turn one function into many -- case 1 gcd, case 2 divide, case 3 multiply, etc. I don't think your definition of "single recursive pass" is useful.

Comment: @MattT I agree: you could reduce any starting `Nat` to `1` by the Collatz procedure, using only the same auxiliaries. That would also be a "single recursive pass". Good luck proving any properties of the procedure -- like it is terminating, or space use.

Comment: Minor comment: using `is_zero, succ, pred` and tail recursion you can simulate any counter machine. Since counter machines are Turing-complete, you can surely implement `reduce_fraction`. This will, however, lead to an abysmal complexity.

Comment: Keep in mind I'm also looking for the least amount of parameters needed to do this. Interesting comments regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write a straightforward function that mimics the same `gcd` structure you have, but which returns the fraction in reduced form:

```
-- redBad n d delta reduces the fraction (n+delta)/(d+delta)
redBad 0 0 delta = (1, 1)
redBad 0 d delta = case redBad delta d 0 of
    (n', d') -> (n', n'+d')
redBad n 0 delta = case redBad n delta 0 of
    (n', d') -> (n'+d', d')
redBad n d delta = redBad (n-1) (d-1) (delta+1)
```

"Ah!", you shout, "but that uses an auxiliary function named `+`"! Okay, no problem; we'll use the "mode" trick described in the comments. Mode 0 is the gcd calculation; mode 1 is the addition calculation.

```
-- redGood n d delta 0 reduces the fraction (n+delta)/(d+delta)
-- redGood n d delta 1 produces the fraction (n+delta)/d
redGood 0 0 delta 0 = (1, 1)
redGood 0 d delta 0 = case redGood delta d 0 0 of
    (n', d') -> case redGood d' n' n' 1 of
        (d'', n'') -> (n'', d'')
redGood n 0 delta 0 = case redGood n delta 0 0 of
    (n', d') -> redGood n' d' d' 1
redGood n d delta 0 = redGood (n-1) (d-1) (delta+1) 0
redGood n d 0 mode = (n, d)
redGood n d delta mode = redGood (n+1) d (delta-1) mode
```

Comment: Great answer, and fair. You needed 4 auxiliary variables. I wonder if there is some kind of proof that it is impossible to do with less. I think that's the case.